# Type.GetMethod returns always null

Tags: c#, reflection, methodinfo, stack-frame

I want to get a MethodInfo object from the calling method to determine if there is a special attribute set on that method.

**The Programm class with the calling method Run()**

```
class Program
    {
        private static RestHandler _handler = new RestHandler();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Run();
        }

        [Rest("GET")]
        static void Run()
        {   
            _handler.Handler(typeof(Program));
        }
    }
```

The Class where I would like to determine the custom attribute

```
public class RestHandler
    {
        public void Handler(Type t)
        {
            StackFrame frame = new StackFrame(1);
            var method = frame.GetMethod();

            MethodInfo methodInfo = t.GetMethod(method.Name, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static);

            var attributes = methodInfo.GetCustomAttributes<RestAttribute>();
        }
    }
```

The attribute class

```
 public class RestAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public RestAttribute(string method)
        {
            Method = method;
        }

        public string Method { get; set; }
    }
```

My problem here is that the MethodInfo object (`methodInfo`) is always null even the method object from the stack frame ist set correctly.
The property `method.Name` returns the correct name of the calling method. 
Why the `methodInfo` object is always null?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a private method:

```
static void Run()
```

Add BindingFlags.NonPublic to access it via reflection

```
MethodInfo methodInfo = t.GetMethod(method.Name, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static);
```

Comment: @Kris Can you please mark as answer if it does? Thanks.